# HTML 5 <Canvas>

Tags: html, canvas

Here's my code. Need help with drawing an image of a cloud in between the mountain landscape using html 5 canvas element and javascript code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:2px solid black;"></canvas>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var c= document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var d=c.getContext("2d");

d.beginPath();
d.strokeStyle="red";
d.moveTo(0,50);<!-- width is 0 and height is 50-->
d.lineTo(100,0);
d.moveTo(100,0);<!-- width is 0 and height is 50-->
d.lineTo(150,50);
d.moveTo(150,50);
d.lineTo(200,0);
d.moveTo(200,0);
d.lineTo(300,50);
d.lineTo(0,50);
d.stroke();
d.beginPath();
d.arc(150,15,10,0,2*Math.PI);
d.stroke();
d.beginPath();
d.strokeStyle="black";
d.moveTo(100,100);
d.lineTo(200,100);
d.lineTo(150,60);
d.lineTo(100,100);
d.lineTo(100,150);
d.lineTo(200,150);
d.lineTo(200,100);
d.stroke();
d.moveTo(135,150);
d.lineTo(135,120);
d.lineTo(135,120);
d.lineTo(160,120);
d.lineTo(160,150);
d.stroke();
d.beginPath();
d.arc(20,20,10,.25*Math.PI,.75*Math.PI);
d.stroke();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please add any suitable code below mine to include the image of a cloud

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason/274779#274779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw clouds using cubic Bezier curves.

You can also move and resize the clouds as needed using transforms. The translate command will move the starting [x,y] point of your drawing. The scale command will scale the drawing larger and smaller.

Another set of useful commands is save() and restore(). `context.save()`will save the context state before you change drawing colors or do transformes. `context.restore()` will restore the original context as it existed before the last context.save. Otherwise, you would need to manually undo all the transforms and reset the colors.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var d=canvas.getContext("2d");

d.fillStyle='skyblue';
d.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

cloud(50,100,0.50);

function cloud(x,y,scale){
  d.save();
  d.translate(x,y);
  d.scale(scale,scale);
  d.beginPath();
  d.moveTo(0, 0);
  d.bezierCurveTo(-40,  20, -40,  70,  60,  70);
  d.bezierCurveTo(80,  100, 150, 100, 170,  70);
  d.bezierCurveTo(250,  70, 250,  40, 220,  20);
  d.bezierCurveTo(260, -40, 200, -50, 170, -30);         
  d.bezierCurveTo(150, -75,  80, -60,  80, -30);
  d.bezierCurveTo(30,  -75, -20, -60,   0,   0);
  d.strokeStyle='lightgray';
  d.fillStyle='white';
  d.fill();
  d.stroke();
  d.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: cloud(50,100,0.50);

function cloud(x,y,scale){
  d.save();
  d.translate(x,y);
  d.scale(scale,scale); wasn't sure about this section of the code above. Can you explain please ?

Comment: The drawing commands make a cloud in the upper left corner of the canvas. d.translate(x,y) will push the cloud so its upper left corner is at x,y. Similarly, the cloud is drawn at a fixed size. If you want a larger or smaller cloud, you can send in a scaling factor (scale) that will draw the cloud larger or smaller. Both translate and scale are called transforms. Transforms are permanent until they are changed so your own next drawing commands will be translated and scaled by my code. Save() and restore()  limit my transform from affecting your own drawings. Cheers!

Comment: This was a very clearly explained solution. Although it did not answer my original question which required creating clouds with arc command it certainly provided a good alternative. Thankyou !

Comment: Using arc() was not noted as a requirement stated in your statement; you also did not ask a question, you simply said 'Need help..'.

To create a cloud using arc(), you would simply create a number of overlapping circles.
This would be an inflexible approach and would not be recommended.

Comment: @jared, A closed path of Bezier curves is more flexible than a patch of overlapping white dots--not less flexible. You can apply a silver `context.stroke()` and the cloud could have a silver lining! You could fill that closed path with a white-to-gray `gradient`  and the cloud would be a threatening thundercloud! But if you prefer patches of circular white dots then you should use patches of circular white dots ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@markE Apologies, my message was unclear.

I 100% agree with you. I upvoted your answer because it is absolutely the correct and most flexible way to do this! I assumed OP would have loved your answer.

I was surprised to read, after your thorough explanation, that @newbie said "..it did not answer my original question which required creating clouds with arc...". 
I was just trying to answer him, but was trying to point out that using arc() would be inflexible and not recommended.

Sorry for the misinterpretation.

I should just rewrite my response to say: "Ditto what @markE said" :)